Object reference not set to an instance of an object, but I have a value inside it
So, something very strange is happening. This is different from normal object reference error so do not close this topic.
I have ViewBag that is having a value and I'm passing it to view.
ViewBag.NumberOfPictures = numberOfPictures;    

and numberOfPictures have value 1.
Inside the Razor view I have
    int numberOfPictures = ViewBag.NumberOfPictures;

and use it inside the view like:
 @if (numberOfPictures == 1)


but it says numberOfPictures is null (I get object reference)...
Any solution? Couple days ago everything was working normally.
I tried put a new viewBag and try. I get an error again.

An int cannot be null, the error you see must be referring to another variable.

Yes, I know, and numberOfPictures variable has a value of 1, or 2 or 3 always.
